# What is it called when a word is translated phonetically from a foreign language to English?

Tags: translation, phonetics

For example, the word "jihad." Translated, the word means "struggle" or "strive" and I am sure there are others. The word "jihad," is just taking the pronunciation of the word in the native tongue, and spelling it phonetically in English. Is there a specific word for that?

Comment: The word is a *[loanword](http://www.bl.uk/learning/langlit/changlang/activities/lang/twentieth/loanwords.html)*. The process of writing it according to English orthographic conventions is *[transliteration](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158054)*, and its normalization to English forms is *[anglicisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicisation)* / *anglicization* .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That practice is called *[transcription](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/transcription)*:

> 1.2 A form in which a speech sound or a foreign character is represented:
>
> ODO

***Transliteration*** is not necessarily a phonetic operation:

> *[Transliterate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/transliterate?q=transliteration#transliterate__23)*:
>
> Write or print (a letter or word) using the closest corresponding
> letters of a different alphabet or language:
>
> ODO

Because Arabic has a dissimilar alphabet system, جهاد‎ ǧihād [dʒiˈhæːd] comes across as a phonetic transliteration, which is technically *transcription*.

There are specific principles of *[transcription](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Arabic)* applied to each language separatey.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Arabic
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Hebrew
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian

Comment: 背広. in roman letters *sebiro* is the Japanese word meaning a *business suit*. Many people assume it is a Japanese word, especially as it has its own *kanji* character. In fact it is the Japanese pronunciation of *Saville Row*, the London street which for at least 150 years has been the epitome of high-class tailoring. There is a similar Japanese word *waishatsu* meaning *shirt*, which is simply a Japanese pronunciation of *white shirt*. These were items of clothing unknown to the Japanese before the *Meiji Restoration*. They are simply phonetic interpretations.

Comment: So English borrows from itself via Japanese!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. My examples were of Japanese borrowing from English. I think there are examples of Russian doing the same thing. Someone told me the Russian for a railway station was a *Vauxhall*. But I remain to be convinced about that one.

Comment: @WS2: A Russian railway station is a *vokzal*. But that's the [etymology](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/вокзал).

Comment: @WS2 [Вокзал](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB) but the name was attributed to the pleasure gardens

Comment: @Henry How interesting!  And what a loss to London the pleasure gardens must have been  when they closed permanently in 1859.

Comment: @ScotM Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for. I never expected such immediate responses. I can't believe I have gone this long without stack exchange.